# OSX: Making sure Dropbox always starts after SD card is mounted?

Tags: macos, boot, mount, dropbox, sd-card

I have a Macbook Pro with a relatively small SSD, so I use a 128GB MicroSD card in a nifty little adapter I plug flush into the side of the laptop for some extra storage.  I have quite a large Dropbox, and I decided to move my Dropbox to the MicroSD.

Now, every time I boot up, the Dropbox app starts up before my SD card finishes mounting, and it complains that the Dropbox folder is missing.  If I tell it to just exit, and then I restart the Dropbox app after the SD card is mounted, everything is fine from then on.

Is there any way I can change my boot sequence so that the Dropbox app will wait for the SD card mount to complete before it tries to start up?  Is this possible?  It would be nice, because I keep forgetting that I cancelled the Dropbox startup and then I never start it up and I miss file updates.  Then I remember and turn it on and have to sync lots of changes all at once.  I'd like it to just work, like it would if my Dropbox folder was on the OSX disk.

Sorry if I'm asking this in the wrong place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I think I got this to work (it has just now after reboot) by making Dropbox open last in the list in system preferences>users & groups>user name > login items

For good measure I also added the SD card above it in the list (click - to remove Dropbox then + to add Transcend (or whatever your SD card is called) then + to add Dropbox again so its below it - this is the app not the folder!)

Hope that helps.

Comment: That list isn't the load order, it's just a... list. There's no way to control the load order there, you have to take additional steps. See [link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122431/how-to-control-order-of-startup-items-for-users-at-login) for some suggestions.

Comment: Ok thanks blm I stand corrected.  Maybe fiddling with the list does something, though as it seemed to cure the start up problem.  That said it still appears on resume when dropbox can't find the SD again, so maybe it didn't really.  This didn't use to be a problem with dropbox, perhaps this has started happening since upgrading to el capitan.  Or maybe it's something else.... Grrr